# Migrate Android app google sign in to another GCP project

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-signin

We have implemented the google sign in our Android app using the GoogleSignIn client. The client ids were added to Google Cloud Platform, signing keys SHA-1 were added to the firebase console config, and we have downloaded google-services.json and included in the project. Everything works fine, app is released and has active users we don’t want to break.

Now because of some business reasons we need to integrate google sign in our app with a service that is already using another Google Cloud Platform project. We tried generating new keys Android OAuth keys but were blocked by the following quote:

> The package name and fingerprint pair you provided is already used by an Android OAuth 2.0 client ID in this project or another project.

After removing the debug client ID in the old project we generated a new id in the new GCP project, but it fails on a client calls to google SDK and broke google sign-in on the clients using the older id.

On iOS generating key on the new project and swapping it with current one was enough to get it to work.

1. Can our app stay in the current GCP/firebase project and integrate with backend using another GCP project?
2. Is there a way to migrate current app to the backend GCP project without breaking currently released app (which is cooperating with a backend using the same GCP project)?

Comment: Hey, did you solve this? I'm facing a similar issue now 

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, we avoided it by moving our sign-in to web-based Auth0 in the next release